# How can I diagnose problems with Perl's getc?

Tags: perl, getc

I am having this strange problems with the `getc` function. I use `getc` to get a character from a socket file handler. I need to simulate message exchanges between pc and a mobile device. For the first few messages, `getc` works fine. But for this one, `getc` couldn't get anything from the socket. The whole Perl program blocked until I reset that mobile device. But the wireshark shows the message was send to the right port number.

Is there tool I can use to what's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common source of problems with file and socket handles is that the end of input can be reached and the handles error or eof flag could be set. Try calling `seek HANDLE,0,1` to reset the handle after a call to `getc` doesn't return anything (or should it be `sysseek`? Is `getc` a buffered I/O operation?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I use wireshark and capture an extra Fin,Ack sends from tcp client which cause the next 3-way handshakes get out of sync. I fix the problem by use the same socket from previous test. It looks good now.